# tabbed browsing by storing webView in an Array/plist?

Tags: ios, browser, uiwebview, tabbed

I want to build a tab-Browser and so far I've implemented everything (Bookmarks, settings...) except tabbed browsing.

What I know so far is that I should store my `webView` in an array or a dictionary and then retrieve it. but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I've tried so far in various variations:

```
[mainDrowser.webView removeFromSuperview]; 
mainDrowser.webView = [mainDrowser.arrayForTest objectAtIndex:anIndex];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

The view does appear, but it doesn't have the content of the saved webView but the content of the one I just removed.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Also something I tried:

```
-(IBAction) saveAsTab:(id)sender {
    [tabDictionary setValue:addressField.text forKey:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
    NSLog(@"tabDictionary: %@", tabDictionary);
    [tabData setValue:webView forKey: addressField.text];
    NSLog(@"tabData: %@", tabData);
```

-(void) showWebViewFromDictionaryAtKey:(NSString *)urlForWebView {

```
[webView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:(UIWebView *)[tabData valueForKey:urlForWebView]];
```

}

In another class:

```
DrowserAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    DrowserViewController *mainDrowser = [appDelegate drowserViewController];
    NSString *urlStringForWebView = [mainDrowser.tabDictionary valueForKey:cellTitle];

    [mainDrowser showWebViewFromDictionaryAtKey:urlStringForWebView];
```

This doesn't work either. Same problem

I also tried to change the webView by not removing and adding it. Is it possible that if I store a webView in an array the content isn't stored but only the properties of the view?

Does anyone have an idea if it might work with a private framework? this app is just for fun and not for the AppStore

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind. I made a stupid noobish mistake (I'm very new to developing, only 3 weeks of experience :D)

I have to create a new instance of UIWebView for each tab.

sorry for this mistake.